# Best way to adjust non-responsive websites to window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, zooming

I've built a non-responsive website (it's an "experimental/artistic" site with too many things happening on the screen to make it responsive..)

I am excluding mobile phones obviously but I want to make it available to tablets as well

Now the site has a width of 1280px so it's not going to show properly on tablets either

However, I can zoom out the body of my site accordingly, when the user is on a tablet correct ?

Do you think the script below will do the trick :

```
var resizeSite = function (originalWidth, minWidth)
{
   var resize = function ()
   {
      var currentWidth = $(window).width();
      var zoom = currentWidth / originalWidth;

      if ((currentWidth < originalWidth) && (currentWidth >= minWidth))
      {          
         $('body').css({
            zoom: zoom,
           '-moz-transform' : 'scale(' + zoom + ')'
         });
      }
   };

   resize();

   $(window).resize(function ()
   {
      resize();
   });
};

resizeSite(1280, 980);
```

Zooming out obviously distorts the quality but it's better than nothing I guess.

Is there a better option or is there something wrong with the above script ?

Is there a way to prevent the text from being blurred (for certain zoom values) when zooming out ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the viewport meta tag to your header. What it does is set the width of the screen to match the width of the device. There are several options associated to the viewport tag so take a look at the following link for more information. :-)

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks! According to this article : http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho the viewport meta tag should not be used with non-responsive websites so I guess I'll stick to my sloppy solution" for now :-)